# Symfony 5.2 add to session array

Tags: arrays, symfony, session

I want to add product to my session array but always it overwriting existing product and is only one.

```
    /**
     * @Route("/{id}", name="add", methods={"GET"})
    */

  public function add(Product $product, Request $request): Response
   {
       $session= $request->getSession();
       $session->set('products', array(
           'list' => $product,
       ));
       $this->addFlash('success', 'add');
       return $this->render('index.html.twig', [
           'product' => $product
        ]);
    }
```

any suggestion?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Is it even related to Symfony, or the concept of sessions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You overwrite the session variable each time instead of adding a new product. Try to get the product, add new product, then set the session:

```
public function add(Product $product, Request $request): Response
{
   $session= $request->getSession();
   $products = $session->get('products', []);
   $session->set('products', array(
       'list' => array_merge($products['list'] ?? [], [$product]) 
   ));
   $this->addFlash('success', 'add');
   return $this->render('index.html.twig', [
       'product' => $product
    ]);
}
```

If you want to have distinct products you may use product['id'] as the key

```
public function add(Product $product, Request $request): Response
{
   $session= $request->getSession();
   $products = $session->get('products', []);
   $products[$product['id']] = $product;
   $session->set('products', products);
   $this->addFlash('success', 'add');
   return $this->render('index.html.twig', [
       'product' => $product
    ]);
}
```

Comment: and how i can add to no repeat product, somethink like this " if(isset($products['id']))" ?